# android device Battery health showing overheat even though battery is in normal temperature

Tags: android, linux-kernel

DUMP OF SERVICE batterystats:
Battery History (0% used, 1584 used of 256KB, 6 strings using 492):
                    0 (9) RESET:TIME: 2016-03-07-15-59-54
                    0 (2) 092 c2501424 status=not-charging health=overheat plug=none temp=373 volt=4030 +running +wake_lock +mobile_radio +audio +screen data_conn=hspa phone_signal_strength=great brightness=bright fg=1000:"com.catalina.logdump"
                    0 (2) 092 c2501424 top=u0a68:"com.honeywell.testtools.suspendresumetest"
                    0 (2) 092 c2501424 user=0:"0"
                    0 (2) 092 c2501424 userfg=0:"0"
                +69ms (2) 092 c2501424 status=discharging

AS the battery temp=373, it is showing health=overheat,  That should not happen at all. Because of this health=overheat device notification LED will blink in RED.

Can anybody give me solution please.

I got the error in the kernel as
1) <3>[18810.893554, 1] bq27000-battery bq27000-battery: error reading register 18: -1

2)<3>[19205.674407, 0] bq27000-battery bq27000-battery: error reading nominal available capacity

3) BatteryService: Battery Led Mode is null

Along with this I am attaching bugreport file.

Comment: What are you actually asking for here? A bugfix you can attach to their bugtracker along with the bug report?

Comment: sorry not attaching bugreport file. It is not allowing me to upload file.

Comment: Use thirdparty apps like mediafire to upload it and send the link here. Cheers!